# How to reduce or increase the squares while maintaining their absolute positioning?

Tags: java, javafx

[image: illustrative example №1]
[image: illustrative example №2]

In the window, the user sees a field that is composed of a set of squares. The field is generated randomly. (But it doesn’t matter, just boasted of its work: DDDD) When the user scrolls the mouse wheel, depending on the direction of the scroll, the squares should either increase or decrease. So, when this happens, the squares do not change their coordinates, as a result of which the effect appears as in the second picture. A gap is formed between them! How to make them positioned according to their size?

If necessary, here is my code. Do not take to heart.:DDD

```
scene.setOnScroll(e -> 
    {
        if(e.getDeltaY() > 0)
            {
        camera.cameraControlScale(camera.cameraControlGetScaleX()+0.25, 
        camera.cameraControlGetScaleY()+0.25);
            }
        else
            {

        camera.cameraControlScale(camera.cameraControlGetScaleX()-0.25, 
        camera.cameraControlGetScaleY()-0.25);
            }
     });



protected void objectControlScale(double x, double y)
    {
        imageview.setScaleX(x);
        imageview.setScaleY(y);
    }
protected double objectControlGetScaleY()
    {
        return imageview.getScaleY();
    }
protected double objectControlGetScaleX()
    {
        return imageview.getScaleX();
    }
```

Here I place my functions in the listener.^
The content of the functions is simple and how it should be non-working!:DDD
Yes, I know, I have work with a picture here in functions, but what difference does it make? There are pictures on the field, but for clarity, I removed them. They have the exact same problem.
You do not have to bother writing code, I will be grateful if you show where to read about it, solve such problems, etc.

The `Rectangle`s/`ImageView`s are directly added to the scene root:

```
Pane root = new Pane(... children ...);
```

Comment: What do you use as parent for those `ImageView`s/`Rectangle`s? Is this parent the root or are there more nodes in the scene hierarchy?

Comment: @fabian parent is root. Pane root = new Pane(and here are added pictures and a rectangles);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pivot point of scale transformations applied using `scaleX` and `scaleY` is the center of a node. Furthermore the position of the nodes is not changed automatically.

Assuming you want to scale all children of the `root` pane, it's simplest to apply the transformation to the `Pane` itself:

```
Pane realRoot = new Pane(root);
```

```
root.setScaleX(x);
root.setScaleY(y);
```

---

Other alternatives include creating a `GridPane` and wrapping every one of the `Rectangle`s/`ImageView`s in a `Group`.

If you want to determine the position of the children yourself though AND want to use independent scale factors for every single child, things get a bit more complicated: After all updates you need to adjust the positions of all nodes based on the `boundsInParent` properties...